# Q_OBJECT and Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION . How and why we need to define the qt_metacast and qt_metacall

Tags: qt

I am new to QT and from last week I have started to work in a project where QT is used. I didn't understand the Q_OBJECT macro. It's included in a header file and using a cpp file some properties like metacast and metacall are defined. What is this property and why it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt provides extensions to the C++ language, such as the meta-object system, which provides the signals and slots mechanism for inter-object communication, run-time type information, and the dynamic property system.

In order for a class to use the extensions, it must declare the macro Q_OBJECT. The moc (Meta Object Compiler) then provides each class with the necessary code for the additional features.

I suggest reading the Qt documentation on [metaobjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html) and the [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) to gain a better understanding and then ask questions if there's anything else you want clarification on.